# How to wrap iterator of boost::circular_buffer?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to use boost::circular_buffer to manage fixed size of the queue.

To do that, I wrap boost::circular_buffer by using class `Something`.

```
class Something {
  public:
    Something();
  private:
    boost::circular_buffer<int> buffer;
};
```

Here, the problem is that class `Something` should wrap iterator of `buffer`.

For example, If I use `std::vector<int>`, it is simple:

```
class Something {
  public:
    Something();
    typedef std::vector<int>::iterator Iterator;
    
    Iterator begin() { return buffer.begin(); }
    Iterator end() { return buffer.end(); }
    ...
  private:
    std::vector<int> buffer;
};
```

How to use `boost::circular_buffer` to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the exact same thing as you do with the `std::vector`.

`typedef std::vector<int>::iterator Iterator;` declares a local type called `Iterator` that is an alias for `std::vector<int>`'s iterator type.

So logically, you should be able to just swap out the `std::vector<int>` for a `boost::circular_buffer<int>` and it should just drop in:

```cpp
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>

class Something {
  public:
    Something();

    typedef boost::circular_buffer<int>::iterator Iterator;
    
    Iterator begin() { return buffer.begin(); }
    Iterator end() { return buffer.end(); }

  private:
    boost::circular_buffer<int> buffer;
};
```

You can clean this up further a bit by using a second type alias for the container itself. This way, you can change the container type by altering a single line of code, and everything else flows from there.

```
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>

class Something {
  public:

    Something();

    using container_type = boost::circular_buffer<int>;
    using iterator = container_type::iterator;
    
    iterator begin() { return buffer.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return buffer.end(); }

  private:
    container_type buffer;
};
```

N.B. I used `using` instead of `typedef` since it's generally considered easier to read in modern code, but the meaning is the same.

Comment: Thank you. This is correct. I thought that `boost::circular_buffer<int>::iterator` does not exist due to my mistake in compilation.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is `begin` and `end`, you can simply use `auto` return type
(or `decltype(auto)` for general case)

```cpp
class Something {
  public:
    Something();
    auto begin() { return buffer.begin(); }
    auto end() { return buffer.end(); }
  private:
    boost::circular_buffer<int> buffer;
};
```